# Windows doesn't correctly detect partition migrated from old disk with ntfsclone

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, partition-copy

I am trying to migrate a Windows partition (NTFS) from an old 1TB disk to a new 3TB disk.

To do this, I connected both disks, booted into Ubuntu Live, created a new partition (using GPartEd) on the new disk, and used `ntfsclone` to clone the partition. Since the new partition was bigger (the whole point of migrating to the new disk), I also used GPartEd to "Check" the new partition which supposedly dealt with the partition size discrepancy.

The new partition works fine in Ubuntu Live (I can browse around, has the right label and size, etc.) but not in Windows 7. If I go to Disk Manager, I see the new partition as a "Healthy (Primary Partition)" of the correct size, but there is no drive letter assigned. If I right click, only the "Delete Volume" entry is enabled (even "Properties" is disabled!).

If I fire up `diskpart` at a console, here is what I see:

```
DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C                NTFS   Partition    244 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1                      FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type             Size     Offset
  -------------  ---------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    System            100 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Reserved          128 MB   101 MB
  Partition 3    Primary           244 GB   229 MB
* Partition 4    Unknown          2257 GB   244 GB

DISKPART> detail partition

Partition 4
Type    : 0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4
Hidden  : Yes
Required: No
Attrib  : 0000000000000000
Offset in Bytes: 262384123905
```

I'm not terribly familiar with administering Windows, so I'm not sure what all this means. *It seems that Windows doesn't recognize that Partition 4 is an NTFS partition, which I imagine is the root of the problem.* The `Hidden: Yes` has me a little worried too, but I (speculatively) imagine it is a symptom of not recognizing the partition type. Any ideas how to address this? Hopefully without wiping the partition and making me have to copy it again?

Comment: First question I have is the disk using MBR or GPT?  Because 3TB presents problems if its MBR.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
Type    : 0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4
```

That type code identifies a Linux filesystem partition. You must change the type code to EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7. I'm not sure how you'd do that in Windows' `diskpart`. In my own [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/), you'd change the type code from 8300 to 0700. (`gdisk` uses two-byte hexadecimal values as shorthand for the 16-byte GUID codes that are used internally by GPT.)